# Get contents of gapi Object

Tags: php

I want to pull some Google Analytics data through GAPI. However, what I'm getting back is an `array` in an `Object` in an `array`. I don't know how to get the data out of this.

This is the response:

```
gapiReportEntry Object ( [metrics:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array ( [pageviews] => 102 [visits] => 79 [avgTimeOnSite] => 30.569620253165 [percentNewVisits] => 98.73417721519 [visitBounceRate] => 77.215189873418 [UniquePageviews] => 92 ) [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array ( [browser] => Safari (in-app) ) )
```

And this is the code I ran:

```
define('ga_email','my_email');
define('ga_password','my_password');
define('ga_profile_id',$analyticsid);

require('Including/php/gapi-1.3/gapi.class.php');

$number = 0;

while($number < 3) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-".$number." days"));

    $ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
    //$dimensions, $metrics, $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date=null, $end_date=null, $start_index=1, $max_results=30)
    $request = $ga->requestReportData(
        ga_profile_id,
        array('browser'),
        array('pageviews','visits','avgTimeOnSite','percentNewVisits','visitBounceRate','UniquePageviews',),
        array('-visits'), 
        null, 
        $date,
        $date,
        1,
        30
    );

    ${'data'.$number} = $request;

    $number++;

}
```

And then `print_r($data0[0]);` gives me this result.

Comment: you need to be a little more specific, what code did you run to result in this output?

Comment: I'm sorry, first time here. I added it to the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

you wrote ... 

    "browser'),
            array('pageviews','visits','avgTimeOnSite','percentNewVisits','visitBounceRate','UniquePageviews',),
            array('-visits'"

 ... The output does display this information...

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php for details.

I believe you need to do something along the lines of:

    echo objectname->attribute;

Comment: what language are you working with? ...I would say it looks like php, but your output looks more like javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Gapi.class.php you should use `$request->getVisits();` to get the visitcount, for the pageviews you would use `$request->getPageviews();` etc.